# Adding Column to GridView data source and bind data to it at run time, C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a task which requires binding data to a gridview which has 7 columns. Six columns of the gridview are binded to dataset from a database with sql command... I need to bind the last column dynamically at run time to a data which comes from file at run time.  Is there a mechanism to add 7th column to datasource at run time and then bind it's value? 
.
.

```
 e.Row.Cells(7).Text = f.Name.ToLower.Replace(CStr(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "LicenseName")).ToLower, "").Replace(".7z", "").Trim
```

.
.
this is how i got the value

Comment: CStr()? Did you mean to tag this as VB, not C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need a template column, like this :

```
<Columns>
    ...
     ...

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSeventhCol" runat="server" 
                ondatabinding="lblSeventhCol_DataBinding"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and

```
protected void lblSeventhCol_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Label).Text = GetDynamicData();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort to support me but I am destined to solve my problem the other way. I fetched the data from the database on datatable, then add the the 7th column to datatable, then insert values of rows of the 7th column onrowdatabaound()...and finally change the datasource of the gridview to the dataset/datatable. ....The task I have to finish now is to handle sorting, deleting , paging, cancel etc events  by hardcoding. If I need assistance on that...I hope you will be at my disposal.